# Effecient way of updating a Map from a List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures

Given I have a `LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean>` and an `ArrayList<String>`, how do I update `LinkedHashMap` based on keys?

The solution I can think of is:

```
private void updateFilesPath(LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean) map,ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (String filePath : list)
        if (map.get(filePath) == null)
            map.put(filePath, true);
}
```

But This soloution is `O(n^2)` (n times iterating and searching in the collection with time complexity `O(n)`)
Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this. Can you do one step back and explain a  bit more of your use case?

Comment: any particular reason for using linkedhashmap?

Comment: @Marvin the boolean values are used to determine if a checklist has been checked. the constructor offers araylist for creattion of the item.so I should update hashmap myself to refrence the checked items

Comment: @Ravjit Singh Uppal you have better DS in mind?

Comment: Judging from the way what you're trying to achieve, why can't you use a Set , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html. If the filepath contains in Set you know for sure that file has been checked

Comment: Just use a hashmap, you will have O(nlogn) time complexity

Comment: @Bunti right, but the user can check an unchecked item, so I can't delete item from set.I should keep a reference on item anyway. That's how I think. Any other point of views appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then it should be just a matter of using `forEach` to add the new values:

```
filePath.forEach(key -> map.put(key, true));
```

If you only want to update it if it isn't present, then:

```
filePath.forEach(key -> map.putIfAbsent(key, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap or HashTable  or Arrays or TreeMap have the search complexity O(n). You can use B Tree which has O(log(n)) complexity.